# Android emulator in Docker

Tags: android, jenkins, docker

I`m trying to start Android emulator inside docker container, but I get error:

```
root@686d602e6ffa:~/android-sdk-linux/tools# ./emulator            
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:

       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.

       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

But the OS inside container is (`uname -a`)

`Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:06:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And manually starting emulatox64-x86 works fine:

```
android-sdk-linux/tools# ./emulator64-x86 
emulator: ERROR: You did not provide the name of an Android Virtual Device
with the '-avd <name>' option. Read -help-avd for more information.

If you *really* want to *NOT* run an AVD, consider using '-data <file>'
to specify a data partition image file (I hope you know what you're doing).
```

I may make a symbolic link - but I think it is not a good solution because there may be different architecture to emulate

Also this emulator should be started by Jenkins which live in container mentioned above

**UPDATED:**
As @user2915097 suggested: 

  `root@686d602e6ffa:/# file /bin/bash
  /bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),        dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24`

Comment: Apart from `emulator` acting weird, is there any reason not to use `emulator64-x86`? (As far as I can see I guess that saves the day for me and I hadn't seen this solution in your question at first.)

Comment: I think only reason is that I do not know what exactlyy does `emulator` executable. May be it adds some flags to actual emulators or something else, so plasing I simulink instead of actual program **may** be dangerous


Nevertheless it is solution

Comment: I'm running into this problem now myself too, What did you find to be your solution?

Comment: You may make a symbolic link  - see below with the name android which will direct to emulator64-x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make a symbolic link - but I think it is not a good solution because there may be different architecture to emulate

Answer (score 3):

As just an FYI: I ran into this on docker based off of `FROM ubuntu:16.04`
 and finally solved it by installing "file" `apt-get install file`

Apparently emulator uses `file` to look at $SHELL and if it doesn't contain "x86_64" it thinks it is 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

extract from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/611

uname will always tell you 64 bits. Look at e.g. "file /bin/sh" to see the real arch of the filesystem.

Comment: `root@686d602e6ffa:/# file /bin/bash`
   `/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),     dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux     2.6.24,BuildID[sha1]=54967822da027467f21e65a1eac7576dec7dd821,     stripped`


    `root@686d602e6ffa:~/android-sdk-linux/tools# file emulator`
    `emulator: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped`


The same I get on the host PC (which is pure x64) and all is fine